# Change All Values in a Column over a Number of Characters in R

Tags: r

Hello I have a table in R and I would like to replace all the values that are over 15 characters with "No_Assignment", is this possible?

Comment: You can use `df1$column[nchar(df1$column) > 15] <- "No_Assignment"` (assuming the column is `character` class)

Comment: Hello (thanks for taking the time to help) worked great cheers! Post an answer and I'll approve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the column is `character` class we get the number of characters with `nchar` check if that is greater than 15 and assign those elements to the string

```
df1$yourcolumn[nchar(df1$yourcolumn) > 15] <- "No_Assignment"
```

NOTE: Change the 'yourcolumn' to the column name of the dataset